# Manipulating Big Numbers as strings

Tags: c, string, numbers

I have a problem that goes:

Create a C program that inputs large integers as strings.
Then every character is converted into the corresponding digit.

After that I have to create a function `addBigNumbers()` that has 3 matrices.

```
addBigNumbers(char *a1, char *a2, char *res)
```

**a1** and **a2** will contain the 2 large numbers that I want to add,**res** will contain the sum of those as a number sequence. We want the function that we created to check if the strings contains numbers only.

If it contains only numbers then **res** equals 1 and it prints the sum of those numbers else **res** is equal to 0 (max number length is **1000**)

After that first function we want to create a function for subtraction.

So far I haven't gotten to subtraction since I stuck in the first one and I need your help.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 1000

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
 int addHugeNumbers(char *a1, char *a2, char *res){
    int y=0, u=0, h=0;
    res=strcat(a1,a2);
    if(strlen(a1)>strlen(a2)){
        y=atoi(a1);
        u=atoi(a2);
        h=y+u;
     }
     else{
        y=atoi(a1);
        u=atoi(a2);
        h=u+y;
     }
     printf("%d", h);
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char res[N];
    char a1[N/2];
    char a2[N/2];
    scanf("%s", &a1);
    scanf("%s", &a2);
    addHugeNumbers(a1, a2, res);


    return 0;
}
```

The problem I have is that if I input **ex. 23 23** it outputs **2346** which is obviously wrong but it got **46** correct, when I input **1234 123** it outputs **1234246** which is all wrong.

Where it gets weird is if i input something like **1234r 123** or anything else that has a character in it, it outputs the exact sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `res=strcat(a1,a2)`, which does something very different than that what you think: it appends `a2` to `a1`, and it does not "create" a new string. See, for example `strcat`-definition at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat):

> **char *strcat( char *dest, const char *src )**
>
> Appends a copy of the null-terminated byte string pointed to by src
>   to the end of the null-terminated byte string pointed to by dest. The
>   character src[0] replaces the null terminator at the end of dest. The
>   resulting byte string is null-terminated.

So you are manipulating your input before calculating something, and that's what you will observe then when using a debugger.

Further, `scanf("%s", &a1)` looks suspicious; it should be `scanf("%s", a1);`. Your compiler should have warned you.

You'd probably rethink `addBigNumbers`, probably adding the digits in a loop rather than converting them to (somehow always) limited integral data types in between. This task is actually nothing for beginners in C; take the following fragment to study:

```
#define N 1000

int addHugeNumbers(char *a1, char *a2, char *res){

    char resultBuffer[N];
    int i1 = (int)strlen(a1);
    int i2 = (int)strlen(a2);
    int carryOver = 0;
    int ri = 0;
    while (i1 > 0 || i2 > 0) {  // until both inputs have been read to their beginning
        i1--;
        i2--;

        // read single digits and consider that a string might have already
        // been read to its beginning
        int d1 = i1 >= 0 ? a1[i1] - '0' : 0;
        int d2 = i2 >= 0 ? a2[i2] - '0' : 0;

        // check for invalid input
        if (d1 < 0 || d1 > 9 || d2 < 0 || d2 > 9) {
            return 0;
        }

        // calculate result digit, taking previous carryOver into account
        int digitSum = d1 + d2 + carryOver;
        carryOver = digitSum / 10;
        digitSum %= 10;

        resultBuffer[ri++] = digitSum + '0';
    }
    // write the last carryOver, if any
    if (carryOver > 0) {
        resultBuffer[ri++] = carryOver + '0';
    }

    // copy resultBuffer into res in reverse order:
    while(ri--) {
        *res++ = resultBuffer[ri];
    }
    // terminate res-string
    *res = '\0';

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char res[N];
    char a1[N/2] = "123412341234";
    char a2[N/2] = "1231";
    if (addHugeNumbers(a1, a2, res)) {
        printf("result: %s\n", res);
    } else {
        printf("invalid number.\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i know what 'strcat' does , but i don't use it anywhere in the output so i don't think it affects the strange behaviour of the ouput .

Comment: @DumDum: it manipulates `a1`, making `"2323"` out of it, for example.

Comment: @Dum Dum: no, result will be in manipulated `a1`. `res` will simply point to the same string as `a1` afterwards, i.e. `res == a1` will be true.

Comment: you are actually right, thanks for the input. But still when i try to add big numbers the output is weird `ex 123123123123123 and 123123123123123` outputs `-1408702618` @StephanLechner

Comment: You are using `int` as datatype, with a maximum representable value of `2147483647` on a 32 bit system. You are very likely exceeding `MAX_INT`, thereby yielding undefined behaviour; often you will observe that - due to 2-complements-representation of negative values, you see negative numbers.

Comment: You'd probably rethink `addBigNumbers`, probably adding the digits in a loop rather than converting them to (somehow always) limited integral data types in between.

Comment: but how can i add them in a loop with a carry @StephanLechner

Comment: Go through the strings a1 and a2 from their end, add their digit value + probably overflow from a previous digit... Try it - if you face problems, post your code and you'll get forward.